# This program is listening on a TCP-socket – which? (& how to find out if it did not state so?)

Tags: jakarta-ee, tcp, cmd

**Hello, I have a scale simulating program, and i need to answer this question but i am having some difficulties. This program is listening on a TCP-socket – which? (& how to find out if it did not state so?)**

**I am very new to this so this, so i dont really know how to do it. I have tried cmd, but am not exactly sure which command and what reading i should take. Or is it so tha i need to write a program in java?**

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay with cmd, you can use `netstat` command. Use `netstat /?` for help. I suppose the simplest way would be to lookup your program in the output of `netstat -nab`.

You can also use [tcpview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) tool from Sysinternals.